# How to use prism RegionManager RegionName in my application

Tags: prism

I found this example of code https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/21-PassingParameters,
but I have to use prism from the beginning in App xaml)

Can I use some parts of Prism solution in my application somewhere in the middle not starting all app with Prism.
Here I am talking about using ContentControl prism RegionManager RegionName ContentRegion

Comment: Can you expand on `not starting all app with Prism`? You don't have to use `PrismApplication` or `BootStrapper`, but you do have to initialize all the components that you want to use.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I cannot use prism before I initialize it at the very beginning in App xaml is that correct?

Comment: You can use all parts of Prism after initializing them, app.xaml.cs is nothing special, e.g. you can use the `EventAggregator` by registering it as singleton and having it injected in your consumers that want to exchange messages.